# The error: cannot resolve host address for machine

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed the ROS in a raspberry 2. I use the code to set  the environment .

```
source environment.sh
```

After that I make the roslaunch and there is an error
code:

```
roslaunch duckietown joystick.launch veh:=wama
```

error:

```
cannot resolve host address for machine [wama]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

My URI is wama.local:11311

I changed the hostname to biecuole, and try to ping the biecuole and biecuole.local. They both work but the error is still existing

code:

```
roslaunch duckietown joystick.launch veh:=biecuole... logging to /home/robot2/.ros/log/f4462c94-c3f7-11e7-b0b6-74da38c7fa07/roslaunch-biecuole-8314.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://biecuole.local:32874/
remote[biecuole.local-0] starting roslaunch
remote[biecuole.local-0]: creating ssh connection to biecuole.local:22, user[zhang]
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py:141: FutureWarning: CTR mode needs counter parameter, not IV
  self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
remote[biecuole.local-0]: failed to launch on biecuole:

Unable to establish ssh connection to [zhang@biecuole.local:22]: Server u'biecuole.local' not found in known_hosts

[biecuole.local-0] killing on exit
unable to start remote roslaunch child: biecuole.local-0
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274841/the-error:-cannot-resolve-host-address-for-machine-..../) by [adadada](https://answers.ros.org/users/32480/adadada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-03**:
Does `ping wama` in a command terminal work? If not, that is the problem.

**Comment by [adadada](https://answers.ros.org/users/32480/adadada/) on 2017-11-07**:
I changed the hostname to biecuole, and try to ping the biecuole and biecuole.local. They both work but the error is still existing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> Unable to establish ssh connection to [zhang@biecuole.local:22]: Server u'biecuole.local' not found in known_hosts
> ```

This error simply tells you that the host you are trying to connect to (using SSH) is not yet known to your own system (ie: the machine *from which* you are trying to connect to others).

Logging in once with `ssh` (in a regular terminal session) should solve this (make sure to first check #q41446 though).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [adadada](https://answers.ros.org/users/32480/adadada/) on 2017-11-07**:
I can ssh the biecuole and biecuole.local
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.38-v7+ armv7l)

- Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
- Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
- Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
  I already used the code in 41446,  it does not help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-08**:
If you ever connected through SSH without adding the option that #q41446 mentions, `ssh` will not do anything, which could mean that the current entry in `known_hosts` uses the wrong algorithm.

Just in case, remove any entries for `biecuole` and `biecuole.local` and try again.